# Example of splitting of prime ideals

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals, ramification

I am trying to figure out how prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ decompose in the Galois extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{7})/\mathbb{Q}$.

And so, for this, I've picked the prime ideals $5\mathbb{Z}$, $7\mathbb{Z}$ and $29\mathbb{Z}$ to learn with an example.

From what I understand, the first step is to factor the minimal polinomial of $\zeta_{7}$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$)

\begin{equation}
p(x)=x^{6}+x^{5}+x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1
\end{equation}

modulo 5 (resp. 7 and 29), so I know the "form" of the ideals above $5\mathbb{Z}$ (resp. $7\mathbb{Z}$ and $29\mathbb{Z}$).

(I can do this for every prime in this example because $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{7}]$ is exactly the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{7})$, right? I know this can be more carefully stated in terms of something called "conductor".)

We get

\begin{equation}
p(x)\equiv x^{6}+x^{5}+x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1\mod 5
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
p(x)\equiv (x-1)^{6}\mod 7
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
p(x)\equiv (x-7)(x-16)(x-20)(x-23)(x-24)(x-25)\mod 29
\end{equation}

This means that we can write

\begin{equation}
5\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{7}]\:\text{is a prime ideal}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
7\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{7}]=(\zeta_{7}-1)^{6}\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{7}]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
29\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{7}]=(\zeta_{7}-6)(\zeta_{7}-16)(\zeta_{7}-20)(\zeta_{7}-23)(\zeta_{7}-24)(\zeta_{7}-25)\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{7}]
\end{equation}

And so, 5 is inert, 7 ramifies and 29 splits completely.

Is this correct?

The easiest way to find this decomposition for p is by reducing the polynomial mod p? It took me a while to do this. In this particular extension, can I completely characterize which primes behave like 5, 7 and 29? Also, is there another type of behaviour that my example didn't show?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular extension, because it’s cyclotomic, your task is considerably simplified.

No matter over what field $\Bbb F_p$ you consider your polynomial $P(x)=(x^7-1)/(x-1)$, it’s always the polynomial whose roots are the seventh roots of unity. Now, how big a field $\Bbb F_{p^m}$ do you need to go to to get the seventh roots of unity? In the case $p=5$, you see that $5^6-1$ is the first such that $5^m-1$ is divisible by $7$. Oho.

Oho! You’re asking for the smallest $m$ such that $7|(p^m-1)$, i.e. such that $7k=p^m-1$, i.e. such that $p^m\equiv1\pmod7$. Oho. You’re asking for the period of $p$ in $\Bbb F_7^*\>$(!). No matter what this $m$ is that you find, that’s the degree of the irreducible factors of $P$ over $\Bbb F_p$. For $p=5$, $P$ is still irreducible, for $p=11$, it factors into two cubics, and for $p=29$, $P$ is the product of six linears.

Oh yes, and for $p=7$, you should write out $P(x+1)$ as a $\Bbb Z$-polynomial.